# SSL error when adding cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Getting this error message: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when i activate my (www) (foobar.com) and (en) on cloudflare. 
I have tried to contact them and read the articles but no good response.

The site istelf has a wildcard sll from rapid ssl. And i am suspecting there is a conflict of some sorts with the ssl cloudflare is providing.

But thats why i am here, i dont really know. The site is unaccessible from any browser/ip. Its just the error message that i described over that shows. So when i greyed out all of the clouds in cloudflare settings it worked again.

But i want to benefit from cloudlfare so it cant be like this. My site is on a free cloudflare plan.

Somebody know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you activating Cloudflare through a hosting partner? Some Cloudflare hosting providers are yet to [enable Universal SSL on their service](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/222612707).

On Cloudflare's free plan, their SSL certificates can sometimes take up to [24 hours to validate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ); paid Cloudflare plans validate SSL certificates near instantly. If you still face issues, you should review their [SSL FAQ](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ), you can file a support ticket at the bottom of that page if you still can't find an answer. One such case where you will need to contact Cloudflare support is if your domain has triggered a brand check to verify that there is no misappropriate usage of a brand/country name.